# FFMPEG Add Concat to Combined commands

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

here is my current code

```
ffmpeg -i "Video.mp4" -i "Watermark.png" -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:09:32 -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" "Video-Out.mp4"
```

i have an intro video which i want to combine alongside the above command so it adds the intro video then the Video-Out.mp4

intro video > trimmed video with watermark combined as one

note* the intro video is a different codec since i exported it via sony vegas

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i Video.mp4 -i intro.mp4`

Comment: here is the output for trimming and adding watermark: https://pastebin.com/wLYaKxwA

Comment: That's missing some info. Ideally it would show the ffmpeg version and compilation options, and the info about each input stream. I'm not concerned about the output info.

Comment: the output works fine, no issue just after having intro added at start and having it as one command than export with watermark > concat intro + video output

unless you are after the codecs?

Comment: I need to see the details of the inputs so I can give you a detailed example command. Otherwise I can only give you a very generic example that may not work with your specific inputs.

Comment: no problem, thanks, here the full output from the export using the above command i listed: https://pastebin.com/28stc0M2

Comment: This is missing info about the intro file that is to be concatenated. Please show the output of `ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png`. Again, without it I can't give you a command you can simply copy and paste.